# Cygwin bash shell script complains about

Tags: bash, for-loop, cygwin

I created the following file in Windows Notepad:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(ls) do $i done
```

Note that the file has three lines (the last one is empty).

When I run the script, I get the error message:

```
$ ./script
./script: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Removing the last line (that is, ending the file right after "done") does not change anything.

I suspect this has to do with the CR+LF v. LF difference between Unix and Windows, but I thought Cygwin was expected to deal with that; since it runs on a Windows platform, it would make sense for it to be able to deal with text files created in that same platform.

So why am I seeing this error?

Comment: This is basically the same as your other question, only the context is different. Whereas the interactive shell posts a secondary prompt for you to complete the `for` loop, the non-interactive shell (which reads from the file and not standard input) simply runs out of input and displays an error instead of prompting you for more.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I change the file to
for i in *<newline>
do<newline>
    echo $i<newline>
done
I get
./script: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
Any idea why?

Comment: Because your file uses DOS line endings (CR/LF); `bash` expects POSIX line endings (LF) and treats the initial carriage return in the CR/LF pair as a regular (non-whitespace) character.